# Webpage with lots of images: slow scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scroll

I have a webpage with a news feed. And the news feed has a bunch of images stacked vertically. New images populate the page as the user scrolls downwards.

Things start off fast and smooth, but as more images load (and more scrolling down) the page starts to get really slow and choppy. Scrolling becomes super unsmooth.

**What's the problem? And how can I fix this?**

Comment: Do you have a demo page?

Comment: You should describe the problem in much more detail , Like including some Code . Anyway I'll try to answer it . Try optimizing the images by reducing the size . Next time Please include details like Browser , its version , operating system , page source code etc.

Comment: Are you using javascript to do anything with the page/images, could explain the performance hit as time goes on. Need more information.

Comment: Are you specifying the width and height of the images in the markup?  And is the browser having to do any computation to fit the images into that space (ie. are the images the size the markup says they are)?

Comment: @Pauly Dee this is super old but do you recall how you resolved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LazyLoad for JQuery ([link](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload)).  It doesn't load images until you scroll down, so perfect for your use case.

Comment: I already do. It's not the image loading that's causing problems. It seems to be the sheer number of images in the feed.

Comment: Can you try paginating the results so they are not on one page?

Answer (score 0):

How big are the images you are using? You should try to make image sizes as small as possible.

You could try pre-loading the images in JavaScript (`Image` object). That way, when the user scrolls down, the images are already loaded (or partly loaded).

Comment: None are very big. Average: 300x400. That's as small as they can be. And I already do make sure the images are loaded. It just seems that when there's tons of images on the page (even if loaded) scrolling becomes choppy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a bug in your javascript.
If not, you could try to delete the newest pictures when older ones are loaded.

Comment: When using jQuery does the `.remove()` method work on this case ?